# Functorial description of irreducibility of topological space?

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

This is a crosspost of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2341682/functorial-description-of-irreducibility-of-topological-space).

---

A topological space is connected if it's not the coproduct of two non-trivial spaces. Equivalently, it is connected if the copresheaf it represents preserves coproducts.

A topological space is irreducible if it's not the union of proper closed subsets, or alternatively if every pair of non-trivial opens has inhabited intersection. Does irreducibility admit a functorial description?

Comment: Maybe in terms of the corresponding locale? Just a thought...

Comment: By the way, I wish I could +1 your user page, handy code and all.

Comment: Martin Brandenburg [points out](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450193/is-there-a-suitable-definition-in-categories-for-a-closed-continuous-function-in) that there's a "brute force" categorical characterization of the Sierpinski space. From there, you can talk about closed sets categorically and so also irreducibility. But somehow this is not terribly satisfying.

Comment: You could try to find a similar categorical description of the space $T$ with elements $\{x,y,z\}$ and nontrivial closed sets $\{x,y\}$, $\{y,z\}$, and $\{y\}$. Then maps $f:X\to T$ with $x$ and $z$ in the image indicate that $f^{-1}(\{x,y\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{y,z\})$ are proper closed subsets covering $X$.